# Expected Sum of n numbers after m random opeartions on range of n numbers.

Tags: probability, expectation

I have been given **25** objects numbered from **1 to 25** and a set **S** = {`-2, -1, 0, 1, 2`}. I have to choose a random number from the given set and add it to all objects from **1 to 5**.
Again choose a random number and add it to objects from **15 to 25** and again choose a random number and add it to objects from **5 to 12**, indexing of objects is 1 based.What will be the expected sum of all objects after all 3 turns?

Comment: This looks like deviation from previous question you asked so if you are asking about questions from your homework, please show what you have come up with so far

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- What is the sum of what you started with?
- What is the expected amount you add?
- Hence, what is the expected sum of what you finish with?

See: [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity)